# What TF2 items can I sell to the Steam Community Market?

Tags: team-fortress-2, steam-community-market

I have over 150 items in my TF2 inventory, but all I can sell are my crates, keys, and Genuine Items. How do I know what is eligible for selling, and what is not?

Is it actually possible to sell any item from my TF2 inventory? (Do I have to, say, sign up for another Steam Service before I can freely sell all my items?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, you do need a premium account to sell items. The [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Steam_Community_Market) also says that "In order to sell an item on the Steam Community Market, the user must buy one item on Steam per year, and then wait 30 days after purchase to begin buying or selling."

It's also limited to tradable Genuine items, Vintage items, Festive (both Unique and Strange) weapons, Botkiller weapons, Strange weapons, Unusual hats, crates, and most if not all tools.

You can see what items of your inventory can be sold by using the "Show marketable borders only" option of the backpack viewer. This also shows how much is the item selling for.

[image: Backpack with "Show marketable borders only" selected in the middle, near the top. A Genuine item is highlighted, with the end of its tooltip saying, "(50 available on the Steam Community Market starting at 6,87€)"]

Comment: Thanks! But, er, could you elaborate on what a "tool" is?

Comment: @avestar101 Basically just usable items—keys, paints, tags, gift wrap, etc.—but I haven't checked all items.

Comment: I did have a premium account and I also can add friends but I also can not sell any of my tf2 items what could I sell? FYI this is not right

Comment: @William He means a TF2 Premium Account, not just a Steam one. You can get this buy purchasing something in the Mann Co. store.

Answer (score 2):

Genuine items, crates, keys, vintages, tools (name tag, desc tag, decal, etc.), paint, strange parts, backpack expander, festive items, manniversary package, strange botkillers, gifts, unusuals, strange festives, strangifiers, strange filters, and strange hats...
think i got that down right

Answer (score 0):

As an added answer, any user can sell Unique weapons, provided the weapons have a Killstreak kit on it.

Valve has also added the ability to sell:

- ***Unique*** (Killstreak, Specialized, Professional) weapons
- ***Collector***'s quality weapons/hats/miscs
- ***Killstreak*** Kits
- ***Specialized*** Killstreak Kits
- ***Specialized*** Killstreak Fabricators
- ***Professional*** Killstreak Kits
- ***Professional*** Killstreak Fabricators
- ***Haunted*** Halloween items (Side Note: Some haunteds are unmarketable.)